# Why is the project I made in Eclipse empty?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my first time using Eclipse 3.3.2 to make an application in Java. I went to File -> New Java Project, and created a new project called "NewProject."

A new folder named "NewProject" was created in my workspace with two empty folders: one named "src" and one named "bin." I then close Eclipse and try to reopen my newly created "project." However, I cannot do so. Eclipse just treats the project folder as any other folder. Why?

Comment: And what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I am developing a Java application :) I have to open it first though.

Comment: Are you trying to _open_ or _import an existing project_? You should be doing the latter.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you! Importing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java source files go into the `src` folder and Eclipse continuously compiles them into the `bin` folder.

Since you haven't created any source files you don't see anything in your project.

Comment: Thank you, but then how do I open my project to add a source file in the first place? I can't even open it. Eclipse just treats my project folder as a normal folder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "treats it as a normal folder" but if you are in the "Project Explorer" (or similar) view then you can right-click the "src" folder and create a new class.

Comment: Oh, I see. The only way to open a project in Eclipse is via Project Explorer. Thanks!